# Tapestry: How to scroll horizontal in Palette

Tags: css, tapestry, horizontal-scrolling, palette

I have items in Palette that is wider than the box width. The tail-end of items is clipped and not visible. Palette has automatic vertical scrolling but not horizontal scrolling. How do I make horizontal scrolling possible?

Here is what I have tried at my css.

```
DIV.t-palette SELECT { 
overflow-x: auto !important;
}
```

and

```
DIV.t-palette-available {
     overflow-x: auto !important;   
}
```

and

```
DIV.t-palette {
    overflow-x: auto !important;    
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i'm not understanding your question, but this worked for me:

```
DIV.t-palette SELECT {
 overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but it doesn't work for me. Are you using t:type="Palette" or are you using the tapestry-jquery palette?